# I want to map indexes of my variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash

```
NList=(5)
VList=(1)
FList=("input/flower1.jpg" "input/flower2.jpg" "input/flower3.jpg" "input/flower4.jpg")
IList=("320X240"            "640X480"           "1280X960"          "1920X1200")
SList=(2 3)
for VM in ${VList[@]}; do

    for ((index=0; index < ${#FList};)) do
        file=$FList[$index]
        image_size=$IList[$index]
        width=`echo $image_size|cut -d "X" -f1`
        height=`echo $image_size|cut -d "X" -f2`
        for scale_factor in ${SList[@]}; do
            for users in ${NList[@]}; do 
                echo "V: $VM, " "F: $file, " "S: $scale_factor, " "I: $width $height , " "N: $users"
                for i in `seq 1 $users` ; do
                    ./sr_run_once.sh $file $width $height $scale_factor &
                done
                wait
            done # for users            
        done # for scale_factor
    done # for index
done # for VM
exit 0
```

i want that the Flistsay flower1 should just process image size of `320*240`
hence introduced the variable index... but unable to get a hang of it. it gives an error.

Comment: `IFS=X read width height <<< "$image_size"` should work to set those variables, although you'll want to verify that prior to `bash` 4.3, which fixed some bugs when setting `IFS` for a command reading from a here string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few syntax errors in there. I've annotated them in comments:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^-- shebang for bash because you use bash extensions.    

NList=(5)
VList=(1)
FList=("input/flower1.jpg" "input/flower2.jpg" "input/flower3.jpg" "input/flower4.jpg")
IList=("320X240"            "640X480"           "1280X960"          "1920X1200")
SList=(2 3)

for VM in ${VList[@]}; do
                           #  +-- You've used the right syntax above, you have
                           #  |   to use it here as well.
                           #  |
                           #  |             +--- and here you have to increment
                           #  v             v    the index to move forward.
    for ((index=0; $index < ${#FList[@]}; ++index)) do

        #     v--- the braces here are not optional.
        file=${FList[$index]}
        image_size=${IList[$index]}
        width=`echo $image_size|cut -d "X" -f1`
        height=`echo $image_size|cut -d "X" -f2`
        for scale_factor in ${SList[@]}; do
            for users in ${NList[@]}; do 
                echo "V: $VM, " "F: $file, " "S: $scale_factor, " "I: $width $height , " "N: $users"
                for i in `seq 1 $users` ; do
                    ./sr_run_once.sh $file $width $height $scale_factor &
                done
                wait
            done # for users            
        done # for scale_factor
    done # for index
done # for VM
exit 0
```

Comment: Variables inside the C-style for loop are treated as arithmetic expressions, so `index < ${#FList[@]}` would work just fine.

Comment: Oh, you are right. That's kind of nifty, since it provides pointer variables of a sort. I mean like `var=i; for (($var = 0; $var < 10; ++$var)) { echo $i; }`. Anyway, I better fix that in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You probably don't actually want to write code like that, though :)

Comment: Hi i tried ie. the index++ and ran the script but it gives an output that i dont want. ie.

0
V: 1,  F: input/flower1.jpg,[0],  S: 2,  I: 320 240,[0] ,  N: 5
PID=18591
PID=18592
PID=18595
PID=18593
V: 1,  F: input/flower1.jpg,[0],  S: 3,  I: 320 240,[0] ,  N: 5
PID=18650
PID=18647
PID=18648
PID=18651
PID=18649

1
V: 1,  F: input/flower1.jpg,[1],  S: 2,  I: 320 240,[1] ,  N: 5
PID=18711
PID=18710
PID=18712
PID=18709
PID=18713
V: 1,  F: input/flower1.jpg,[1],  S: 3,  I: 320 240,[1] ,  N: 5
PID=18766
PID=18769
PID=18765
PID=18768

Comment: I want the image file say flower1 to just take 320*240 image size. hence i thought introducing the index would do that. I do not want to hardcode the script by , If else loops... but be able to just use the index in some way.. 
the image say flower2 shouldnt map to 320*240 but sshould only take 640*480..
I hope i am not being confusing

Comment: This looks as though you hadn't put the brackets around `file=${FList[$index]}` and `image_size=${IList[$index]}`.